# Minimize longest continuous streak of $1$s after flipping $m$ $-1$s to $1$s

Tags: number-theory, searching

Given an array a of length n of $-1$s and $1$s, and another input $m$, I was supposed to minimize the longest continuous streak of $1$s or $-1$s after flipping $m$ $-1$s to $1$s or vice versa.

I know how to maximize it but can't figure out how to minimize it. I maximize the number of $1's$ by sliding window method. 
Take a window ($wleft$ , $wright$).It covers given array from index $wleft$ to $wright$.
I represent $-1$ with $0$ for ease.Suppose number of zeros in window in $wzeros$.

Algorithm :

```
while wright < length of array {

     wzeros <= m: increment wright

     wzeros>m: increment wleft 

  // Update the max window size during this whole process. 

        int temp = wright-wleft;
        if(temp > mx_length){
          mx_length = temp;
          solution_window = wleft;      
        }       
    }
```

This code maximizes the number of consecutive $1$s whereas I want to minimize the number of consecutive $1$s and $-1($or $0)$s. How do I modify the algorithm/code to achieve so ?

Comment: You need entirely different ideas to minimize the maximal run length. Just forget what you did previously, and start thinking afresh.

Comment: Can you please replace your code with pseudocode?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus That's why I was asking for help. And I hope the algorithm suffices.

Comment: Don't answer this question. It's from an ongoing contest. link : https://www.codechef.com/MARCH17/problems/SCHEDULE

Answer (score 1):

You can use dynamic programming. It is very likely that much faster algorithms exist.

Given a string $w$ of length $n$, for $0 \leq i,j \leq n$ and $0 \leq k \leq m$ you compute the minimal maximum 1-run in $w_1,\ldots,w_i$ given that $k$ many -1s were changed to 1s, and given that $w_1,\ldots,w_i$ ends in a 1-run of length $j$.

This gives an $O(n^2m) = O(n^3)$ algorithm.

Comment: Can you explain your way with a pseudocode ?

Comment: It's better you work it out on your own.

Comment: Can you give a hint to start ? I can't think how to start it ?

Comment: My entire answer is one big hint.